# storing differnent values in database for same column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a beginner to databases.I am working on site where i have to save education qualification in database for different users.for e.g

> There is a user Alex.He is graduate in Computer science from Singapore
>   University in 2006. He is also masters in Computer Science from Canada
>   University in 2009.

It will be different for different users.

Should i try a new table for all the education qualification and give id to user table.

```
Select * from users,education;
```

How can i save this in database keeping best practices in mind ?

Thanks In advance. :)

Comment: There is a lot of info on that eg http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to [normalize](https://courses.washington.edu/info200/win12/Readings/dbNormalization.htm) your data, which means remove redundancies and inconsistencies. While you can get away with doing a very crude version of the layout with 2 tables where you allow a user to have multiple educations, you'll want to make sure that you're not creating more work for yourself going down the road.

The problem with the 2 table layout is that you may have records for the same schools, degrees, or majors, but they may be entered differently.

So if you did a search like `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN education
ON users.user_id=education.user_id WHERE education.major LIKE '%Computer Science%' you might not return all of the results for related majors if some of the majors are entered as something like "CompSci."

So you might actually have multiple tables. An example of these multiple tables might be:

- users
- user_degrees
- schools
- degree_types
- majors
- states
- countries

Your table structure for `user_degrees` might look something like this:

- user_degree_id (INT)
- user_id (INT)
- school_id (INT)
- degree_type_id (INT)
- major_id (INT)
- graduation_year (DATETIME)

Schools would look something like this:

- school_id (INT)
- school_name (TINYTEXT)
- school_city (VARCHAR(45))
- state_id (INT)
- country_id (INT)

Degree types might be:

- Associate of Arts
- Associate of Science
- Bachelor of Arts
- Masters
- Doctorate
- etc

There are [several other types of degrees](http://typesofdegrees.org/).

You get the idea. Basically, the premise is that you enter the information for each type of record once, then you can cross relate that information with the various tables without needing to enter it again. Also it allows a global change to any records using that same information.

Here you can [read more about Database normalization](https://courses.washington.edu/info200/win12/Readings/dbNormalization.htm).

Comment: yes you are right but making so many tables is not a solution.I can make users and education table
Structure of education:
user_id
school
degree
year
description

Will it work fine ?

Comment: For every profile user also have work experience, test passed, Awards and achievement and other experience that can have more than 1 entry for every user.Should i create a new table for every type ?

Comment: Where you don't make the data structure rigid you have to make the code or application that supports the system more rigid. While you wouldn't necessarily need 20 tables, you probably should do more than just 2. Also it will make the filesize on the database much smaller if you're not storing duplicate information. You asked for best practices though and data normalization is *The most important Best Practice.*

Comment: You wouldn't create a new table for every type, but you would want to have a table that stored consistent dataforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you explain a bit what about consistent dataforms

Comment: If you have two tables that contain similar information, like in your case, *degrees* and *majors* you would have an `ID` for both, both have `titles`, so you could add another field, a switch, that would indicate the type of record `rec_type`. That way it would be one less table. Then 1 could be degrees, then 2 could be majors.

Answer (score 0):

You must have created 2 tables like users and education

Users table structure is like 
id username etc etc

education
id user_id course/degree

then you can fetch is like

```
select * from users as u ,education as e where u.id = e.user_id
```

Comment: Do you want to tell him why?

Comment: It there any other way to do so because suppose if we have 10000 users and there are 2 education qualification for every user,it will make 20000 entries in education table.

Comment: the above relationship of table defines like users hasMany degree.. in this situation it the best ..

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ - please tell us if you have anything different, all of us would like to learn different methods

Comment: But i think adding a new table for every education qualification is not a good idea.Is there any other way out ?

Comment: @SunilVashist you are inserting a record for every new education qualification not creating a new one.

Comment: yeah @justrohu I got it.

Comment: I've provided a brief overview of database normalization with references. Took a little while to cite a couple of sources.